# Can I get an Ontario Photo Card as a temporary resident?

Tags: canada, identification, ontario

I am a temporary resident of Ontario, on a three year Work Permit.  When applying for a credit card, I was told I was required to have an [Ontario Photo Card](http://www.ontario.ca/government/ontario-photo-card).  Can I get such a card if I am temporarily in Canada on a work permit?

Comment: Going along with your other question, I'd just get the driver's license, to be honest.

Comment: @AnnaLear I will look into that, but it depends on the conditions (if I need to do a new test to get an Ontario license, give up my Dutch license, then in some years do a new test to get a Dutch license, I'd only do that if unavoidable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. All the instructions you need are on the page you linked:

> You can apply for an Ontario Photo Card if you:
>
> - do not drive
> - are a resident of Ontario, and
> - are 16 years of age and older
>
> You will need to bring to a ServiceOntario centre:
>
> - original identity documents to prove your legal name, date of birth and signature

You should be able to bring your work permit (#9 on "list 1" of [accepted documents](http://www.ontario.ca/government/acceptable-identity-documents-ontario-photo-card)) to prove your legal name, date of birth, and signature. There are a few docs on that list that sound like they could satisfy that requirement for you, but they all seem to be basically the same form (IMM 1442).